# batch file about syntax and result

Tags: batch-file, random

> compare.txt:

```
a_max<=a_min
```

---

> Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%n in (1 1 9) do 

set \a "is_p=%random%"
set \a "n=%random%"
set \a "a_max=%random%"
set \a "a_min=%random%"
set \a "a_min=%random%"
if "is_p%2"=="1" (%is_p%=1)
if "is_p%2"=="0" (%is_p%=0)
for %%n in (compare.txt) do ( 
 %a_min%=%random%
)
echo %is_p% %n% %a_max% %a_min% >> input.txt 
allsort < input.txt > results.txt
)
```

---

> The result in input.txt is:

```
12405 220 26501 3870  
12405 220 26501 3870  
12405 220 26501 3870
```

---

> My questions are:

1. I hope to run 9 times in for loop, but actually it did run 3 times.
2. I use %random%, and why the result is the same after each time?
3. I also hope that is_p is either 1 or 0 after if statement, but why actually it is a random number?

---

> P.S

- I'm the beginner of learning how to write batch file, so maybe there are many errors.
- English is not my mother tongue, so please tolerate my poor English,thanks. :)

  To @Stephan,%is_p%=%random% means that I want to assign a random number to the variable,is_p.
  Also, if statement means that if is_p%2=1, set is_p=1.And if is_p%2=0, set is_p=0.

> After correct the code, it can run 9 times, but the result each time is still the same.

Comment: to set a variable, you have to use the `set`command. To get the content of a variable use `%variable%`. Instead of checking if `var %  2`  is 0 or 1 and set the var to 0 or 1 just set the variable to `var % 2` (use %% instead of % because you are in a batch file)

Comment: can you please edit your question to reflect the new (corrected) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) for your first `for` loop use this syntax:

```
for /L %%n in (1 1 9) do (
```

(the missing `(` is probaply a typo?)

2) Your main problem is: in a code block (all variables between `(` and `)` are evaluated at once - so all your %random% is the same.
You will have to `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and use `!random!` instead of `%random%`

-) `%a_min%=%random%` - that's not a valid syntax - what do you try to do?

3)  `if "is_p%2"=="1" (%is_p%=1)` - this does not, what you think it does. I think you mean something like this:

```
set /a is_p=!is_p! %%2
```

(you have to double the percent-sign in Batch)